# dc.js barchart and brush on issue

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to implement interactive data visualization using DC,D3 and CrossFilter JS. But I am facing three issue.

1. Width of the bar in the bar chart
2. Brush is solid black
3. X,Y-Axis lines are too thick.

[image]

I would like to increase width of the bar and like to have Brush on feature with transparent color.

code:

```
    dateChart.width(750)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(timeDim)
    .group(dates)
            .brushOn(true)
    .gap(65)
            .transitionDuration(500)
            .centerBar(true)
   // .xUnits(function(){return 10;})
    .round(d3.time.day.round)
   // .renderlet(colorRenderlet)
    .x(d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 0, 31)])
        .rangeRound([0, 1 * 90]))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .filter([new Date(2016, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 0, 1)])
            .xAxis().tickFormat();
    //.fluctuationChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
```

Comment: Are you including the dc.css file properly? Looks like that's either not including or is failing to load (check your console).

Comment: You are correct dc.css file was not loaded. I corrected it and brush and axis issue is solved. How about width of the bars.

Comment: I figured it out. gap() function is used to increase or decrease the size of the bar.

Comment: `.xUnits()` can also help with bar width